# List all plotly plots in the current environment in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm using `plotly` to generate plots in my code and then using `orca` to save them as pdf files (for incorporating into my LaTeX report). It takes a bit of time to save the plots and I would like to do it all in one shot using a `list` and `lapply`.

I can manually add all the plots to a list and then use `lapply` but was wondering if there's a way to identify all `plotly` plots from `ls()`. Perhps, something similar to `tables()` from `data.table`?

Comment: If you named them in some clever way like myPlot1 myPlot2 or fig1, fig2 etc you can use the `pattern` argument in `ls`. If not, you can pull all of the names, then run through them and extract those having the proper class.

Comment: @lmo you're right - I wasn't using `class` so much as `typeof`. Thanks! It works for me now.